# sql type provider, limit to few tables

Tags: f#, type-providers

Is it possible to limit a sql type provider connection to a few tables? I'm dealing with a huge unsound legacy database. I only want the type provider to analyze a tiny subset of the tables which represent a coherent whole. A subset that I define myself.

Comment: As far as I know, a type provider will actually generate only the types that you actually use. (Or at least it *can* do that, I don't know if SQL provider actually does that.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The F# type providers for SQL are based on LINQ to SQL and LINQ to Entities. In both cases, you can define the schema in a local file and generate types just for those explicitly listed entities. See:

- [Walkthrough: Generating F# Types from an EDMX Schema File (F#)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh361039.aspx)
- [Walkthrough: Generating F# Types from a DBML File (F#)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh361039.aspx)

Both LINQ to SQL and LINQ to Entities give you a way to generate the schema from a live database (so that you do not have to write everything yourself) and you can then remove the tables you do not want to expose. (Although, the caller will still be able to query them using direct SQL query.)

As far as I know (but I may be wrong), the ordinary type providers (like `SqlEntityConnection` and `SqlDataConnection` will actually generate classes for all the tables, because they are just lightweight wrappers for standard .NET tools. But other providers, like those in [F# Data](http://fsharp.github.io/FSharp.Data/) do not generate any types.)

Comment: So in conclusion it is not possible to limit the analysis of the sql type provider to only analyze a subset of the defined tables. You have to do some manual work to remove the tables you are not interested in.

Comment: Yes, you have to do some manual work (but it is not that difficult to do that). In principle, the type provider could make this easier, but the built in one doesn't do that because it is just a thin wrapper over standard .net tools

Comment: Thank you Tomas. I think it would be a very valuable extension to the built in provider.